# 'Accompanying' in a sentence

Tags: grammaticality, syntactic-analysis

> Accompanying these are bowls of zesty, colorful rice and platters
>   filled with ham and fresh salad served with roast turkey.

What does 'accompanying' do in this sentence? 
I don't know its part of speech and structural role in the sentence.
Also I'm not sure if this sentence is grammatical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What an interesting question.

The obvious answer is that it is a present participle, agreeing with all those other things.  In fact, the ordinary continuous present tense of *to accompany* in an extraordinary order.

> All these other goodies are accompanying these.

But if you have it in that more familiar order, it sounds wrong: like something a foreign speaker might say.  It should be “accompany these”

All this illustrates a difference between languages which have cases, as Latin has.  In Latin the order of words that in English is so grammatically necessary to the meaning, is irrelevant to it.

This allows the writer to get away from the *subject - verb - object/complement* and arrange the sentence according to what is important.  The order can be the logical/rhetorical order:

> **Topic** (what you are talking about, which is not necessarily the grammatical subject) - ***Predicate*** (what you are saying about it - the **point being made**.

But sometimes this can be done in English, and your example is a good illustration.  The topic is what goes with whatever had already been mentioned, and the predicate is what these are.

You could have done this in many other ways:

> With these come ...

Rhetorically these orders give you a ‘cliffhanger’ effect.  Not a huge cliffhanger, but one familiar to fans of *Strictly Come Dancing*.

> Going through to Blackpool next week is ...

Comment: Thank you for your sophisticated answer! So can I think of it as a rhetorical inversion?

Comment: I'm still learning English so I'm not sure if I read correctly. Correct me if I'm wrong; The word order in English is stricter than that in Latin. However, this rhetorical inversion still happens in English as in Latin.

Comment: @NiccolòMachiavelli How would you say it in Italian?

Comment: Haha, actually I'm not Italian. It's a google account nickname.